# Running commands from string

Tags: arduino-uno, string, functions

I have a string:

```
string s="digitalWrite(8,LOW);"
```

Is there any way to run it as a code?

Comment: Not an easy way, since you basically would need to write a C/C++ interpreter library for this. I don't know of such a library. Why do you need to do this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: To run commands that will be saved in external eeprom

Comment: Do you really have such complex programs to save there, that you need C syntax text there? Instead you could build your own command structure, which can be way easier to interpret. What commands do you need to save in the EEPROM?

Comment: @chrisl thank you, I forgot that I can do it like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple:

```cpp
if (s == "digitalWrite(8,LOW);") {
    digitalWrite(8,LOW);
}
```

Obviously, it will not work is `s` contains any other string... If you
want something more general, that is able to interpret a wide range of
possible commands, you will have to define a language, and write an
interpreter for that language. From the example you give, it seems you
would like your language to look like C++. This is most likely a bad
design choice. If you want an interpreter that understands the whole C++
language: forget it. You will never fit something this big into an
Arduino Uno.

Here is, for inspiration, [a very simple interpreter](https://gist.github.com/edgar-bonet/607b387260388be77e96) I
wrote that understand the following commands:

```
mode <pin> <mode>: pinMode()
read <pin>: digitalRead()
aread <pin>: analogRead()
write <pin> <value>: digitalWrite()
awrite <pin> <value>: analogWrite()
echo <value>: set echo off (0) or on (1)
```

You can use it a basis for writing your custom interpreter. Otherwise
you can do a Web search for “Arduino interpreter”: you should be able to
find interpreters implementing a wide variety of languages, including
compact binary languages ([Firmata](https://github.com/firmata/arduino)), [Forth](https://flashforth.com/) ([another one](https://github.com/tschaer/tofish)),
[Lisp](http://www.ulisp.com/), [Basic](https://github.com/robinhedwards/ArduinoBASIC), and even [a C-like language](https://n.mtng.org/ele/arduino/iarduino.html).